# How does the second order time constant affect circuit behavior?

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, control-system, transfer-function, passive-networks

I learned that the transfer function of a second order circuit can be expressed in the following standard way:
$$
\frac{K}{\tau_s^2 s^2 + 2 \zeta \tau_s s + 1}
$$
Where:

- \$K\$ is the gain
- \$\zeta\$ is the damping factor
- \$\tau_s\$ is the second order time constant

---

In trying to understand the meaning of \$\tau_s\$, I found [this link](https://apmonitor.com/pdc/index.php/Main/SecondOrderSystems) that states:

> The second order process time constant is the speed that the output response reaches a new steady state condition.

This statement made me have some doubts about how to interpret of this constant.

### My questions:

- Considering, for example, the two transfer functions below:

$$
\begin{array}{c|c}
H_1(s)=\dfrac{5}{2s^2+3s+1} \qquad & \qquad  H_2(s)=\dfrac{5}{8s^2+6s+1}
\end{array}
$$

Both have \$0\$ as the steady state condition. Since \$\tau_2 >\tau_1\$, can we conclude that the output of the circuit represented by \$H_2(s)\$ will reach \$0\$ faster than the one represented by \$H_1(s)\$? Can we conclude that the transient response vanishes faster in \$H_2(s)\$, because it has a bigger time constant?

---

- If we are dealing with an overdamped second order circuit that is a combination of two first order circuits, such as the following

$$
\left(\frac{K}{\tau_{p1}\,s + 1}\right) \left(\frac{1}{\tau_{p2}\,s + 1}\right) = \frac{K}{\tau_{p1}\tau_{p2}\,s^2 + \left(\tau_{p1}+\tau_{p2}\right)s + 1}
$$
         we can say that \$\tau_{p1}\cdot\tau_{p2} = \tau_s^2 \implies \tau_s=\sqrt{\tau_{p1}\cdot\tau_{p2}}\$

If \$T_1\$ is the time constant of one of the cascaded first order circuit \$\left(T_1=-\dfrac{1}{\tau_{p1}}\right)\$ and \$T_2\$ of the other \$\left(T_2=-\dfrac{1}{\tau_{p2}}\right)\$, we have:

$$
\tau_s=\sqrt{\frac{T_1+T_2}{T_1\cdot T_2}}
$$
So, if one defines \$T_s\triangleq \dfrac{1}{\tau_s}\$, will this value have any meaning, like \$T_1\$ and \$T_2\$ have for a first order circuit (for example, the time to decrease/reach certain value)?

---

A correction about the expressions in the second question (thanks to @*TimWescott*):

The poles are \$p_1=-\dfrac{1}{\tau_{p1}}\$ and \$p_2=-\dfrac{1}{\tau_{p2}}\$. Thus, we have:
$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
   T_1=-\dfrac{1}{p_1}=\tau_{p1} \qquad 
 & \qquad T_2=-\dfrac{1}{p_2}=\tau_{p2} \qquad
 &  \qquad \tau_s=\displaystyle\sqrt{T_1\cdot T_2}
\end{array}
$$

Therefore, what I meant was \$T_s\triangleq \tau_s\$. (So, I could have used \$\tau_{p1}\$, \$\tau_{p2}\$ and \$\tau_s\$ directly)

Comment: +1 nice question, good explanation, decent formatting.

Comment: If you want to learn how to combine time constants to form transfer functions, you are ready the fast analytical circuits techniques or FACTs. Have a look at this seminar which is a smooth introduction on the subject: https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202016.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Both have 0 as the steady state condition.

You are confusing *transfer functions* for *signals*.  A transfer function describes a system's behavior; it is a characteristic of some other thing.  A *signal* is more or less a function that evolves in time.

\$H_1\$ and \$H_2\$ both have a DC gain of five, so if the systems they represent are excited by a signal that reaches a steady-state condition, their outputs will each reach a steady-state condition five times the value the input settles to.

> If \$T_1\$ is the time constant of one of the cascaded first order circuit (\$T_1 = −\frac{1}{\tau_{p1}}\$).

**Time** constant implies a variable with units of **seconds**.  Your \$T_1\$ has units of 1/seconds.

> will this value have any meaning, ... for a first order circuit (for example, the time to decrease/reach certain value)?

Not particularly.  Google "dominant pole".  Basically, in a heavily overdamped system that doesn't have significant pole-zero cancellation, the slowest pole wins, and eventually dominates the response.

Comment: So, if i excite both circuits with a step function \$1\,H(t)\$, the output will reach a steady-state. In this case, will \$H_2(s)\$ reach it first because of its time constant?

Comment: Another thing: isn't the unit of \$\tau_{p1}\,1/s\$, so for \$T_1\$, we have \$1/(1/s)=s\$? This make sense to me because \$\tau_s=\sqrt{\tau_{p1}\cdot\tau_{p2}}\$ and it is "a speed". Then, \$\tau_s=\sqrt{\frac{1}{s}\cdot\frac{1}{s}}=\frac{1}{s}\$

Comment: The \$s\$ in \$H(s)\$ is not the unit seconds.  It's a variable, and its units are \$\mathrm{s}^-1\$ (Note the Laplacian \$s\$ is denoted as italic, while seconds \$\mathrm{s}\$ is normal.  Don't blame me, I wasn't born yet when it was established).  I don't recall hearing of a committee from the early 1900's convening to settle on the Most Confusing Variable Name, but they did.

Comment: The time constant of \$H_2\$ is roughly 2.8 seconds, and it is underdamped (if I'm doing my math-in-the-head correctly).  The dominant pole time constant of \$H_1\$ is 2 seconds -- so I would expect \$H_1\$ to settle quicker.

Comment: I know that the \$s\$ in \$H(s)\$ is the complex frequency. But you're right about the units. I was thinking in terms of poles, what I meant to say was \$T_1=-\frac{1}{p_1}\$. Now I realized that \$p_1=-\frac{1}{\tau_{p1}}\$, so \$T_1=\tau_{p1}\$ and \$\tau_s\$ has time unit and not frequency/speed.

Comment: Another thing: so the link I indicate in the question states that \$\tau_s\$ is an _speed_ in the sense of _quickness_ and **not** _velocity_, righ?

Comment: How did you get the value \$2.8\$ for \$H_2\$? Since its written in the standard form, isn't its time constant \$8\,\mathrm{s}\$? And if \$\tau_s\$ is a time constant, why can't I compare it directly: \$\tau_1=2\,\mathrm{s}<\tau_2=8\,\mathrm{s}\$, so \$H_1\$ will reach the steady state first?

Comment: Factor the denominator.  Two poles, their product is 8, so their geometric mean is \$\sqrt{8}\$.  2.8.

Comment: And note -- this is **in your first equation**.  You're diving into the middle of Chapter 3 of a typical 3rd-year dynamic control book -- I think you need to get that book, and start studying it.

Comment: Sorry, I'm messing things up today. I'll try again:
$$
\\
H_1:\tau_1^2=2 \implies \tau_1=\sqrt2\, \mathrm{s} \approx 1.4 \,\mathrm{s} \\
H_2:\tau_2^2=8 \implies \tau_2=\sqrt8 \approx 2.8 \,\mathrm{s}
$$
Since \$\tau_1<\tau_2\$, \$H_1\$ will reach the steady state first. Right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98380/discussion-between-timwescott-and-vinicius-acp).